# How to make a dynamic string to a variable for Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, import

I have a constants.js file that exports many variables and a react example.js page to access these variables at the handleBlur function.

In constants.js:

```
export let vegetable = [{id: vege1, label: Vege 1}]
export let animal = [{id: animal1, label: Animal 1}]
export let toy = [{id: toy1, label: Toy 1}]
```

In example.js:

```
import * as items from './constants.js' 

handleBlur = (event) => {
    console.log(items.vegetable)    
}
```

Currently the `handleBlur` will console log the vegetable's item. The event have values of either `'vegetable'`, `'animal'`, or `'toy'` when I do `event.target.value`. So the question is how do I get the item from the constants file according to the value of the event? I did `console.log('items.' + event.target.value)` which is obviously not going to work because it will console.log a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your object properties with the array notation:

```
handleBlur = (event) => {
  console.log(items[event.target.value])
}
```